# XML Schema Collection breaks xquery

Tags: sql, xml, sql-server-2008, xsd, xquery

The script below can be used to show an example of the problem I have. The script will return an error "There is no element named 'this'".

If I change the declaration of the @XML variable so it is untyped XML (replace the line `DECLARE @XML XML(Test)` with `DECLARE @XML XML`), I do not get the error, but get the expected result instead.

Why do I get the error when using the Schema collection and how can I avoid it - I want to fill a table column with properly typed xml, but I'm having trouble getting my data back out of the column.

```
IF EXISTS (SELECT name FROM sys.xml_schema_collections WHERE name = 'test') DROP XML SCHEMA COLLECTION Test
CREATE XML SCHEMA COLLECTION Test AS
'<xsd:schema xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
      xmlns:t="http://tempuri.org/this.xsd"
      targetNamespace="http://tempuri.org/this.xsd"
      elementFormDefault="qualified">
  <xsd:element name ="this">
    <xsd:complexType>
      <xsd:sequence>
        <xsd:element name="What" minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1" >
          <xsd:simpleType>
            <xsd:restriction base ="xsd:string">
              <xsd:enumeration value ="01."/>
              <xsd:enumeration value ="02."/>
              <xsd:enumeration value ="03."/>
              <xsd:enumeration value ="04."/>
            </xsd:restriction>
          </xsd:simpleType>
        </xsd:element>
        <xsd:element name="When" minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1" >
          <xsd:simpleType>
            <xsd:restriction base ="xsd:string">
              <xsd:enumeration value ="01."/>
              <xsd:enumeration value ="02."/>
            </xsd:restriction>
          </xsd:simpleType>
        </xsd:element>
        <xsd:element name="Outcome" minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1" >
          <xsd:simpleType>
            <xsd:restriction base ="xsd:string">
              <xsd:enumeration value ="one"/>
              <xsd:enumeration value ="two"/>
              <xsd:enumeration value ="whatever"/>
              <xsd:enumeration value =""/>
            </xsd:restriction>
          </xsd:simpleType>
        </xsd:element>
      </xsd:sequence>
    </xsd:complexType>
  </xsd:element>
</xsd:schema>'
GO

    DECLARE @XML XML(Test)

    SET @XML = 
    '<this xmlns="http://tempuri.org/this.xsd">
      <What>02.</What>
      <When>01.</When>
      <Outcome></Outcome>
    </this>'

    SELECT @XML

    SELECT
        Field.value('What[1]','VARCHAR(100)')
    FROM @Xml.nodes('/this') AS this(Field)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is your namespace declaration: `<this xmlns="http://tempuri.org/this.xsd">`. Everything in that XML snippet belongs to the namespace `http://tempuri.org/this.xsd`. Your query used the unqualified name for `this` and `What`. Use this instead:

```
;WITH XMLNAMESPACES (
    'http://tempuri.org/this.xsd' as t
)
SELECT
    Field.value('t:What[1]','VARCHAR(100)')
FROM @Xml.nodes('/t:this') AS this(Field)
```

Comment: Great @ZoffDino, that works perfectly. When you say the problem is with the namespace declaration, does that mean the solution is a workaround; should I change the xml so that the declaration is no longer a problem, or is it correct, but I always need to use `WITH XMLNAMESPACES` line when querying typed xml?

Comment: If you want to keep the namespace, you'll always have to use `WITH XMLNAMESPACES`. If you remove it, you won't have to. Choose one based on your business requirement. I don't recommend one over the other.